# How to read from file and make a HashMap

Tags: c#

**Updated** : to make it clear

I have txt file looks like this

```
a [456545324553645,43456765676564,62644456374,65768475336846,...]
b [3445324553645,4546465676564,07674456374,0906847534657,...]
c [21245324553645,43456765676564,62644456374,6576847534657,...]
d [133426545324553645,43456765676564,62644456374,6576847534657,...]
f [1243545324553645,43456765676564,62644456374,6576847534657,...]
g [356545324553645,43456765676564,62644456374,6576847534657,...]
```

I want to read the file and make a HashMap 
that mean I want to store char in String variable as a Key of Hashmap
and store the numbers in String[] as Value of Hash-map

Comment: What have you completed so far and what do you need help with?

Comment: So taking your example do you want the result to be `string first = { 'a', 'b', ... }`  and `string[] second = { "456545324564534253645", "564356745332567654375", ... }`?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko yup exactly that what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read each line of a file, split it in two, then add each part to wherever it needs to go.

```
string character = "";
string[] numbers; //to be calculated at later

var numberList = new List<string>() // for ease of adding values

using(var file = File.OpenText(pathToFile))
{
        while (!file.EndOfStream)
        {
            var lineParts = file.ReadLine().Split(' '); //split line around space characters
            character += lineParts[0];
            numberList.Add(lineParts[1]);
        }
}

numbers = numberList.ToArray();
```

There are a couple of things to point out here that are good practice.

1. We don't know how big the file is (it could be thousands of lines), so we avoid reading the whole thing at once, instead, only read as much as you need at a time, in this case, a single line.
2. We're not adding straight to the array.  Because of the above, we can't easily work out how many lines there are going to be, so we can't say how big the array needs to be.  Instead we add to a `List`, and turn it into an array later.  If you don't *need* the array, you don't even have to do that: you can just work with the list.
3. The line `character += lineParts[0]` isn't ideal: it creates extra String objects which then have to be thrown away.  Instead, we could use a `StringBuilder`:

   ```
   var characterBuilder = new StringBuilder();

   ...

   characterBuilder.Append(lineParts[0]);

   ...

   character = characterBuilder.ToString();
   ```

   This becomes more relevant as your file gets bigger.

**Update**

If you want to create a hashmap, you're better off creating that from the beginning:

```
var numbers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using(var file = File.OpenText(pathToFile))
{
        while (!file.EndOfStream)
        {
            var lineParts = file.ReadLine().Split(" ".ToCharArray(), 2); //split line around space characters
            numbers[lineParts[0]] = lineParts[1];
        }
}
```

You'll note that I'm using a different overload of `string.Split`.  It takes an int that specifies the maximum number of parts to produce.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for details explicating

Comment: what this line mean ?
numbers[lineParts[0]] = lineParts[1];

Comment: It means, set the entry in the dictionary with key `lineParts[0]` to `lineParts[1]`.  `lineParts[0]` will be the first character, `lineParts[1]` will be the rest of the line.

Comment: Thanks Again 
sorry if i confuse you in the beginning

Comment: In that case, create the dictionary as a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`, and use `linePart[1].Trim ("[]").Split(',')` as the value, et voila, you have your hashmap.

Answer (score 4):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");

var results = lines.Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                   .Select(split => new { Character = split[0], Number = split[1] });

// this is your data, now you can play with it

string allChars = string.Join(string.Empty, results.Select(r => r.Character));
string[] allNumbers = results.Select(r => r.Number).ToArray();
```

Comment: i think it should add toArray in
 string[] allNumbers = results.Select(r => r.Number).toArray ?

any way Thanks it's work

Comment: @Basil Correct, fixed it, thanks.